# Show that $\frac{ -1 }{ 2 } \le \frac{ x }{ 1+x^2 } \le \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

So I'm trying to show that:

$\dfrac{ -1 }{ 2 } \le \dfrac{ x }{ 1+x^2 } \le \dfrac{ 1 }{ 2 }$

for every value of x.

I know I have to use mean value theorem so I tried to show it with cases. First I tried showing that $\dfrac{-1}{2} \le \dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ and then $\dfrac{1}{2} \ge \dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$ using MVT. Is that correct? Can someone guide me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

WLOG $x=\tan y$

$$\implies\dfrac{2x}{1+x^2}=\sin2y$$

Alternatively,

$$\dfrac x{1+x^2}=\dfrac1{x+\dfrac1x}$$

Now if $x>0,\dfrac{x+\dfrac1x}2\ge\sqrt{x\cdot\dfrac1x}=1$

What if $x<0?$

Comment: The sin 2y method is very nice. +1

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why mean value theorem is required as it is much easier to do it like this -

For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$ we know that $$(1+x)^2\geq0\Longrightarrow 1+x^2+2x\geq0\Longrightarrow 2x\geq -(1+x^2)\Longrightarrow \dfrac{x}{1+x^2}\geq-\dfrac{1}{2}$$ Similarly $$(1-x)^2\geq0\Longrightarrow 1+x^2-2x\geq0\Longrightarrow1+x^2\geq2x\Longrightarrow\dfrac{1}{2}\geq\dfrac{x}{1+x^2}$$
And we're done. The only thing we used is that the square of a real number is positive.

Comment: Maybe I was over thinking this haha. MVT is often used to prove inequalities so I thought you would have to use it here somehow. xD .

Comment: That's very clever though! :D .

Comment: @SubhashisChakraborty Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=|x|$, then $\frac{ -1 }{ 2 } \le \frac{ x }{ 1+x^2 } \le \frac{ 1 }{ 2 } \iff  \frac{ u }{ 1+u^2 } \le \frac{ 1 }{ 2 }$.

You are using $AM-GM$ here and not Mean Value Theorem since $1+u^2\geq2u$ by $AM-GM$.

To do the calculus way, just find the derivative of $x\over {1+x^2}$.

$df\over dx$$={1+x^2-2x^2\over{(1+x^2)^2}}=0\implies x=\pm1$.

Sub in $x=1$ you get $f={1\over2}$ and sub in $x=-1$ you get $f={-{1\over2}}$.

And $lim_{x\to \infty}f=0$ shows it is a global maximum. Minimum similarly.

Comment: Technically I would say okay to that solution but the people I am helping actually do not cover it in the syllabus so there must be another way. Any ideas? :/ .

It's a standard calculus I class so I assume there must be a calculus based approach for this.

Comment: In fact, you don't even need AM-GM, just by completing the square: $1 + u^2 - 2u = (u - 1)^2 \geq 0$. I would say that basic techniques such as these (including of AM-GM) have been implicitly assumed in any college-level math courses. I didn't see why MVT is needed to show this simple inequality (it might be better to try avoiding "shooting a mosquito using a cannon" in math).

Comment: Edited to add a calculus way.

Comment: Why would the limit going to 0 imply a maxima/minima?

Comment: The limit as $x\to \infty$ and $x\to -\infty$ are both 0, which is less then $1\over2$. This means if the function goes above $1\over 2$ at any point it will have to do down as some point, which means there must be another local maximum (where derivative is $0$) but there isn't.

Answer (score 1):

$$0\leq(1-x^2)^2\iff 4x^2\leq(1+x^2)^2\iff\frac{x^2}{(1+x^2)^2}\leq\frac14
\iff\left|\frac{x}{1+x^2}\right|\leq\frac12.$$